Email in second address line?
Anyone ever tried using their EMAIL ADDRESS in line 2 of Addresses? If its an alternative address line then an email address makes some sense?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Address line 2 is not for alternative addresses, but rather for additional information regarding the address. For example a tennant in a multi-storey building may input the following to get something delivered to their door:

1234 Example Road
2nd floor, to the left
12345 Example ZIP/City
CA, USA

Or the address may just inherently be very long:

Merdeka Square, Example 123 A
Jalan Lapangan Monas, Gambir, Jakarta
Jakarta 10110,
Indonesia

The point of adding more information is to help the delivery person figure out where to deliver the letter/package/... to, in case just the first line is confusing or not specific enough. Using it for email typically isn't massively helpful as the delivery person won't be able to take meaningful action on it.
That said, adding a phone number or email can be beneficial in case you need to be contacted about something before the actual delivery happens - though that typically happens in its own field instead. Adding it to the address won't help much as the systems in question likely won't look for it there.
